# Remove article id from joomla 3.4.8 url

Tags: joomla

After upgrading my site to Joomla 3.4.8, my URL is showing article id. It was not there before the upgrade.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this problem?

Please help!!
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Joomla, by default, includes the article id in the URL in order to avoid problems with articles having the same aliases.

If the previous version of Joomla did not have the article id in the URL, then it might be that you have been using an extension such as sh404SEF and you're not using it anymore.

It might be also that you had a modified core as explained here: http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-remove-the-article-id-from-joomlas-sef-urls , and the modification was overwritten by the update.

Comment: I have modified the core after upgrading but it is still not working. If there any other way. I dont want to use any extensions.

Comment: It should work with core modification. Try deleting the Joomla cache and see if that helps. We apply the information in the above link on all our clients' websites.

Comment: I tried everything but it is still not working. I think modifying the core does not apply to Joomla 3.4.8 version.